# Can I vectorize scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

`interp1d` works excellently for the individual datasets that I have, however I have in excess of 5 million datasets that I need to have interpolated.

I need the interpolation to be cubic and there should be one interpolation per subset.

Right now I am able to do this with a for loop, however, for 5 million sets to be interpolated, this takes quite some time (15 minutes):

```py
interpolants = []
for i in range(5000000):             
    interpolants.append(interp1d(xArray[i],interpData[i],kind='cubic'))
```

What I'd like to do would maybe look something like this:

```
interpolants = interp1d(xArray, interpData, kind='cubic')
```

This however fails, with the error:

```
ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.
```

Both my x array (xArray) and my y array (interpData) have identical dimensions...

I could parallelize the for loop, but that would only give me a small increase in speed, I'd greatly prefer to vectorize the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to do something similar over the past few days. I finally managed to do it with `np.vectorize`, using [function signatures](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html). Try with the code snippet below:

```
fn_vectorized = np.vectorize(interpolate.interp1d,
                                     signature='(n),(n)->()')
interp_fn_array = fn_vectorized(x[np.newaxis, :, :], y)
```

`x` and `y` are arrays of shape (m x n). The objective was to generate an array of interpolation functions, for row *i* of `x` and row *i* of `y`. The array `interp_fn_array` contains the interpolation functions (shape is (1 x m).